# DocuSign: Is there a permission to use to avoid USER_NOT_ENVELOPE_SENDER_OR_RECIPIENT error?

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect

Using C# SDK, DocuSign API

We have an existing process (under development) whereby our staff can submit signature requests from our website.  These are sent (in the backend code) using a special user in our account.  And the notifications from Connect are also processed using this special user, which includes downloading completed documents.  This is working well.

Since the above process is in it's development stages and we have documents which have to be signed, our staff has been using their user logins within the company DocuSign account to send out documents for signature.  When we get the notifications from DocuSign of a completed envelope and try to download the associated documents, of course we get the -

> "USER_NOT_ENVELOPE_SENDER_OR_RECIPIENT"

error because the account used by the notification processor is not the one that originally sent the request.

Is there a ***limited*** permission I can give this special user account which will let the notification processor download documents and envelope Audit Trail information for any envelope sent from any user in our company DocuSign account?  I'd rather not give this account Admin permissions if I can avoid it.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

thanks,
randy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is to add these users as CC recipients. That means they can view and access the envelope but they do not need to sign it.
It would mean they also get emails about it, if this is a concern, there are other ways to turn this off.

[Custody Transfer](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custody-transfer) probably won't work for you, unless it's ok that the orignal account will no longer have access.

The only other way is to make them administrators which is not **limited** as you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  There is little I can do to affect the behavior of the staff sending out the requests -- I'm just the contractor that writes the code.  Most are too busy to remember to add the CC for this special account and may not understand why it is important.  Which is the primary reason we're trying to get all the requests to eventually be sent from our website.  I may have to go the Admin route.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? We are using DS, and we are having this issue but only for those documents that we receive. For those in which we are the originator, we are able to download the PDF.

Comment: Who sends them to you Paul?